# python reading .txt file, cant remove newline characters

Tags: python, loops

im trying to figure out why it wont let me remove the newline characters, my code:

```
    def parsefile(f):
      for line in open(f):
            li=line.strip()
            if not li.startswith("%"):
                if not li.startswith(' '):
                    if not li.startswith('\n'):

                 print(line.replace("\n",""))
                   #print(line.rstrip())
```

even though i have told it to ignore the '\n' is still leaving spaces in the output, which looks like this

```
    type1

    type2
    type3

    type4
```

when it should just be

```
       type1
       type2
       type3
       type4
```

. my guess is its something to do with my loop leaving the spaces.

the file im accessing is:

```
    %spam 

    type1
    type2
    type3

    %spam
    type4
```

Comment: Replace `print(line)` with `print(li)`. Checking for startswith `\n` or `""` is unnecessary after `strip`.

Comment: @bereal that didnt work, output unchanged

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: Edited to show assessed file

Comment: Ok, so you also want to skip those empty lines, then add `if li:` just after `strip`.

Comment: Are you running Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood, you actually want to skip empty lines, newline chars are already gone after `strip`.

```
def parsefile(f):
    for line in open(f):
        li=line.strip()
        if li and not li.startswith("%"):
            print(li)
```

When you read a file line by line, you're getting every line including empty with the newline chars, so for empty lines you're getting just `"\n"` which becomes `""` after stripping. As explained in the comments, `if li:` in this case is a short for of `if li != "":`.

Comment: so newline and an empty line are different?

Comment: Just to clarify, `if li` here can also be read `if li != ''` which makes sense since `li` is a stripped version of `line` and `'\n'.strip() == ''`

Comment: Worked anyway, thanks a load

Comment: @user1687085 sure they are, I've updated the answer to clarify what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

This option can help you:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f.readlines():
        li=line.lstrip()
        if li and (li[0] != "%"):
            print(li)
```

Note: You can delete left whitespaces using `lstrip`.

Comment: `li[0]` is never `'\n'` after `lstrip()`